# Совместимы ли лицензии GPL3 и BSD3?

Tags: лицензирование, gnu

В программе с лицензией GNU GENERAL PUBLICLICENSE Version3 нужно использовать часть кода с лицензией BSD3 − clause licence. Насколько это юридически допустимо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, вернее не думаю, она как бы со "слабым копилефтом", т.е. не требует открытия исходников и все такое.

Если интересно, то почитай столмоносайт: https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/license-list.html

Comment: Не требует или запрещает открытие исходников?

Comment: Почитайте хотя бы вики. Не требует.

Comment: Спасибо почитал. Правильный ответ - да, допустимо.

Там написано:  
"Лицензия базы данных Беркли (известная также как Лицензия программных продуктов Sleepycat) (Berkeley Database License, Sleepycat Software Product License) (#BerkeleyDB)  
    Это лицензия свободных программ, совместимая с GNU GPL"